# Correct Windows API to find CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties?

Tags: windows, directx, joystick, winmm, setupapi

I'm looking to support a custom joystick device, and due to project requirements I can no longer use the DirectInput API.  I've switched to using the "classic" Windows multimedia API (e.g. **joyGetDevCaps** and family), and it all works with one exception.

The DirectInput DeviceInstance had two fields, **InstanceName** and **ProductName** which returned the correct "custom" name of the device.

The corresponding **joyGetDevCaps** product name field, szPname, returns a generic "Microsoft PC-joystick driver".

In searching the registry on a system with the device installed, I found that there is a REG_SZ **OEMName** entry in this node that has the string I want:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM\VID_07C0&PID_1128

There are two fields returned in the JOYCAPS, wMid (Manufacturer ID) and wPid (Product ID), which map to the two hex values in the keyname: wMid = 0x07c0, wPid = 0x1128.

Additionally, I can use the SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo API on GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID and find a matching controller (although this step may not be necessary):

HID\VID_07C0&PID_1128&REV_1032, HID-compliant game controller

Question: Is there an API for enumerating the MediaProperties\PrivateProperties that I should be using, or is it "safe" to use this information and query the registry directly?  If there's an API please answer with references and/or sample code!  I can't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the szRegName value to get the following key: (in this case, szRegName is "DINPUT.DLL"):

```
HKCU\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaResources\Joystick\DINPUT.DLL\CurrentJoystickSettings
```

It contains values like "Joystick1OEMName", which will contain strings like "VID_07C0&PID_1128" that can be used to look up the appropriate key under PrivateProperties.

Some example code can be found here:
https://github.com/google/liquidfun/blob/master/freeglut/src/mswin/fg_joystick_mswin.c